# Caching MYSQL results using C# console application

Tags: c#, mysql, database, caching

Recently i got into a project which should be console application and uses MySQL database and for that i have to use the cache. The project is the Student/Teacher management system and the requirements are as under :
1) There are 2 types of users, Students and Teachers.
2) Register user
2) Login. Upon login the user will be presented with options which will be saved in database according to the user type and can be changed from there.
3) When a user is logged in the application needs to cache the options so no more database lookups are done.
4) Classrooms. Fill a few dummy rows in the table. A teacher is able to book a classroom. when a classroom is booked it is reserved for 10 minutes. The teacher will have the option to see how many classrooms are booked at any instant...
I have never done the caching before so i have no idea how to implement that into my code. Can anyone please help me out as i have to deliver it tomorrow.
How i will make the delegates and where i have to write the query which will bring all he data corresponding to the user who is logged in.

Thank You.

Answer (score -1):

For caching options, for this particular exercise, you could use .NET Settings.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa730869(v=vs.80).aspx

Comment: But setting do not use the database, as i am at the very beginner level so i can not understand all this. Cn you please explain me hw i will be able to do that with mysql database??